# Inheriting Metadata for Docusign Documents in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, docusignapi

We are using DocuSign for SharePoint Online.  All is working great except for one thing - the document metadata stored with the original Word document is not coming over to the signed PDF file.  Is this how it is supposed to work or are we missing something?

Example: The original Word file has a "Document Type" metadata column set to "Investment Document".  When the signed PDF is added to the library, that metadata field is blank.  We are hoping that it can be filled in with the value associated with the originating Word document.

Answer (score 0):

Kai, thanks for your message.
The existing out-of-the-box integration for SharePoint Online doesn't have this capability. We are looking into the potential enhancement in future releases but it's not yet something we're committing to. Let us know if you want to discuss this further. thanks!